# Intuit Partner Program Legacy List IDs and Txn IDs

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

I have a product that uses the QBSDK to integrate with QuickBooks. My data is linked to List IDs and Txn IDs. From running the test apps and looking at the IPP docs it appears the ids returned by the IPP data services are not List IDs or Txn IDs. It also appears that I do not have a way to access those legacy IDs in order to upgrade my data so it references the new IPP generated IDs.

What are the migration options for someone moving from the QBSDK to the IPP?

Comment: Did you check the Intuit site for documentation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relating Entires from QBSDK to IPP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249682/relating-entires-from-qbsdk-to-ipp)